# Who are the wall cultists?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In episode 14 of *Attack of Titan* season 1, there's a man in a white robe whom Eren calls him the wall cultist.

Who is he?

Comment: If you continue on in the series, a lot more will be explained regarding the cultists. Explanations will likely contain heavy spoilers.

Comment: Asking questions which have a significant impact on the plot will ruin the fun, better not to ask questions (or even search) as they will have heavy spoilers. You can read the manga, which is way ahead of the anime.

Comment: finally completed watching attack on Titan now I understand who the wall cultists are satisfied!!!

Answer (score 1):

For the people inside the walls, these very walls constitute a wonder. No one knows where they came from, only that they protect the residents from a mortal thread. And the walls did a pretty good job for about 100 years.

Now, when people cannot understand something, often they tend to interpret it as a result of divine intervention, especially in times were science isn't as advanced as today. Wall cultists are those who think of the walls as holy. In the time shown in the anime, they got increased influence over the population.

Additionally:

> Science wasn't exactly encouraged within the walls.